# Deriving instances with TypeFamilies

Tags: haskell, types, type-families

I have a type class `Foo` with an associated type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Foo a where
    type Bar a
    foo :: a -> Bar a
```

Now I want to define a data type that holds one of the associated types, and derive a `Show` instance for it:

```
data Baz a = Baz (Bar a) deriving (Show)
```

This doesn't compile, though, because you can't guarantee that there is a `Show` instance for `Bar a`

```
No instance for (Show (Bar a))
  arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
```

I can fix the problem by turning on `FlexibleContexts` and `UndecidableInstances` and writing a manual `Show` instance as follows

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Baz a = Bar a

instance (Show a, Show (Bar a)) => Show (Baz a) where
    showsPrec _ (Baz x) = showString "Baz " . shows x
```

But that's not particularly satisfactory, especially when `Baz` is a more complicated than a simple wrapper around one value, or when I also want to derive instances of other type classes. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `StandaloneDeriving` to ask GHC to generate the same `Show` instance as ever, but with a different context:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, StandaloneDeriving, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Foo a where
    type Bar a
    foo :: a -> Bar a

data Baz a = Baz (Bar a)
deriving instance Show (Bar a) => Show (Baz a)
```

Comment: Is there a theoretical reason the compiler can't just automatically add the `Show (Bar a)` context?  For example, if your data type was `data Baz a = Baz a`, then the compiler would be able to automatically add `Show a`, and there's be no need for standalone deriving.

Comment: @MikeIzbicki I don't think there's a theoretical reason it can't, no. Perhaps a Haskell' proposal for something like `deriving instance of Show Bar` that really does behave exactly the same way as the non-standalone version of deriving is in order.