# type families and deriving instances (Eq)

Tags: haskell, type-families

Is it possible to derive Eq instance for the `B a`, if given additional help, e.g. `Eq a` somewhere?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class A a where
  type B a 
  somef :: a -> B a -> B a -> Bool
```

Question [deriving instances with type families](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144740/deriving-instances-with-typefamilies) and [instance definitions for type families](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491521/haskell-instance-definitions-for-type-families?rq=1) are close. 
The following don't work nor similar modifications on `type B a` -line (or just tried the wrong ones).

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
-- deriving instance Eq (B a) -- illegal application
-- deriving instance Eq a => Eq (B a) -- illegal application
```

Constraining `Eq a => A a` didn't help. Adding constraint to `somef` compiles (`somef :: Eq a => ...`) and works for this method. However, in this case it would be nice to be able to tell that the `type B a` is equatable in general (such that non-equatable B a's would not be allowed) and not method-by-method.

Comment: You want to be able to restrict class instances to types themselves an instance of Eq?

Comment: Yes, to be able to restrict B a -type instances to types that are themselves an instances of Eq.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this does the trick...

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Eq (B a) => A a where
  type B a 
  somef :: a -> B a -> B a -> Bool
```

---

As verification that it works, the following instance is accepted

```
data HasEqInstance = HasEqInstance deriving Eq
instance A () where
  type B () = HasEqInstance
  somef = undefined
```

But this one is rejected with `No instance for (Eq NoEqInstance)`

```
data NoEqInstance = NoEqInstance
instance A () where
  type B () = NoEqInstance
  somef = undefined
```

Comment: Kudos, now it seems so clear (I'm taking my first steps with type families).